# Replace only one value of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list such as:

```
{{{422.624, 422.631}, {423.124, 422.647}, {423.624, 422.671}, {424.124,
   422.704}, {424.624, 422.747}, {425.124, 422.8}, {425.624, 
  422.864}, {426.124, 422.939}, {426.624, 423.026},.....}}
```

How can I replace the very first value of `422.624` for a given value (say 10) while the rest of the list remains the same?

Comment: @Roderic is just a given list that I have. I just would like to replace only one value (the first one) that's it.

Comment: Seems like ReplacePart could help https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html. In your case would be ReplacePart[ list, {1,1,1}->10]

Comment: @Roderic but how to apply it for this particular list? There is only examples of list like {a,b,c..}

Comment: ReplacePart[{{{422.624, 422.631}, {423.124, 422.647}, {423.624, 422.671}, {424.124,
   422.704}, {424.624, 422.747}, {425.124, 422.8}, {425.624, 
  422.864}, {426.124, 422.939}, {426.624, 423.026}}}, {1,1,1}->10]

Comment: `yourList[[1, 1, 1]] = 10`?

Answer (score 4):

Modified input example with duplicates:

```
lst = {{{422.624, 422.631}, {423.124, 424.124}, {424.124, 
     424.124}, {424.124, 422.704}, {424.624, 422.747}, {425.124, 422.8}}};

lst /. 424.124 -> Style[424.124, Red, Bold]
```

[image]

You can use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html) + [`FirstPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FirstPosition.html) as follows:

```
MapAt[10 &, lst, FirstPosition[lst, 424.124]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, define a replacement function that redefines itself after the first replacement:

```
ClearAll[replaceOnce]

replaceOnce[x0_ -> y0_] := Module[{f0}, f0[x_] := If[x == x0, f0[x] = x0; y0, x]; 
    Map[f0, #, {-1}]] &;
```

Replace the first occurrence of `424.124` with `10`:

```
replaceOnce[424.124 -> 10] @ lst
```

> ```
> {{{422.624, 422.631}, {423.124, 10}, {424.124, 424.124}, {424.124, 422.704}, 
>  {424.624, 422.747}, {425.124, 422.8}}}
> ```

Replace the first three occurences of `424.124` with `1000`:

```
Nest[replaceOnce[424.124 -> 1000], lst, 3]
```

> ```
>  {{{422.624, 422.631}, {423.124, 1000}, {1000, 1000}, {424.124, 422.704}, 
>   {424.624, 422.747}, {425.124, 422.8}}}
> ```

A simpler alternative: Change the replacement value after the first replacement:

```
ClearAll[replaceOnce2]

replaceOnce2[x0_ -> y0_] :=  Module[{done = False},
    # /. x0 :> If[done === False, done = True; y0, x0]] &

replaceOnce2[424.124 -> 1000] @ lst
```

> ```
>  {{{422.624, 422.631}, {423.124, 1000}, {424.124, 424.124}, 
>  {424.124, 422.704}, {424.624, 422.747}, {425.124, 422.8}}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There is an ambiguity in your question: do you want to replace the first element of the array, regardless of its value? Or do you want to replace the first occurrence of a number, regardless of its position? In either case, use `ReplacePart`. Here is the second case:

```
SeedRandom[271]
(* list with duplicates *)
lst = ReleaseHold@RandomChoice[{422.624, Hold@RandomReal[1000]}, {10, 2, 2}]
rpos = FirstPosition[lst, 422.624]
ReplacePart[lst, rpos -> 10]
```

For the first case, just use the last line, with `rpos` replaced by `{1,1,1}`, as in the comment of @Roderick.